# Stroongloop, Insert And Update multi Exec

Tags: javascript, node.js, loopbackjs, strongloop

I'm just using loopback last few weeks. I would like to insert in synchronous process. When the first data is inserted into table, then the id will be inserted into the other table.

i've got an error response like this :

```
{"error":{"status":500,"message":"An unknown error occurred"}}
```

my code :

```
   accountModel.create(customerObj.Account, function(error,resp) {
    if(error){
      cb(false, {"message" : "Something Wrong", "err" : error});
    } else {            
      var account_id = resp.result.id;            
      customerObj.Contact.accountId = account_id;
      customerObj.AccountBank.accountId = account_id;
      if(customerObj.Contact){
        contactModel.create(customerObj.Contact, function(err, response) {
          if(err){
            feedbackArr.push({"Contact" : 'error', "err" : err});
          } else {
            feedbackArr.push({"Contact" : 'success', "response" : response});
            if(customerObj.AccountBank){
              bankModel.create(customerObj.AccountBank, function(e,r) {
                if(e){
                  feedbackArr.push({"AccountBank" : 'error', "err" : e});
                } else {
                  feedbackArr.push({"AccountBank" : 'success', "response" : r});
                  cb(true,feedbackArr);
                }
              })
            }
          }
        });
      }
    }
  })
```

All of models base on PersistedModel.
Any ideas ?

Comment: Could be so many factors going wrong here, could you try to address where the error occurs by good old console-logging? What happens if you are missing customerObj.Contact or customerObj.AccountBank?

Comment: Nothing displayed in console. And the data inserted successfully to database.

Comment: I mean, could you try to pinpoint where the actual "unknown error" occurs by doing console.logging till it doesn't log anymore?

Comment: the error response returned when "bankModel.create" process finished. But do not execute callback "cb(true,feedbackArr);"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using Loopbacks CB-mechanism then I recommend you to pass along the error-object instead of true, "cb(true, feedbackArr)" most likely will result in an unknown error, "cb(error, feedbackArr)" will give you a better feedback.

Comment: Thank you sir :) the callback can't use boolean. that's it.